# Simple URL mapping issue

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I would like to map my urls.py to include this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/activity/Arts%20&%20Crafts/member

This url was created by this line of code in my activity.html template:

```
 <li><a href='/activity/{{ activity.name }}/member'>{{ activity.name }}</a></li>
```

Arts & Crafts is the name of an object I've created under the model Activity:

**(models.py)**

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Right now, my url in urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^activity/{{ models.Activity.name }}/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
```

But it doesn't work. When I try to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/activity/Arts%20&%20Crafts/member; I get a 'Page Not Found' error saying "The current URL, activity/Arts & Crafts/member, didn't match any of these."

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my url, and how to fix it? Thank you.

Extra info--
**urls.py:**
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [  
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^detail/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^activity/$', views.ActivityView.as_view(), name='activity'),
    url(r'^activity/{{ models.Activity.name }}/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
class SelectView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'expcore/select_member.html'
  model = Activity
```

Comment: why not to use built in url tags ?
like `{% url 'myapp:view-name' %}`

Comment: @neo-xx Sorry, I'm super new to Django/Python and am not sure what you mean :\ Could you clarify?

Comment: lets say you have a django app `a` and a view  `v` in that app so you can use `{% url 'a:v' %}` and this will generate url which you are trying to generate manually

Comment: also please add the urls.py and views.py

Comment: @neo-xx Added, I'm just using a simplified view for now.

Comment: chk the answer posted and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `urls.py` to capture the name of the activity:

```
url(r'^activity/(?P<activityname>[^/]+)/member/$',
    views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
```

The regex will capture the name of the activity and pass it as a keyword arg to the appropriate method (get or post) of your view function. In that function you can then retrieve the activity name from `kwargs['activityname']` and then retrieve the activity object with the associated name via `Activity.objects.get(name=kwargs['activityname'])`.

Then in your template you can generate the url using

```
<li><a href="{% url 'select_member' activity.name %}">{{ activity.name }}</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really helped.

Comment: Does this mean that I need to include `slug_url_kwarg = 'activityname'` and `slug_field = 'activityname'` in my SelectView view?

I'm trying to get the name of the activity onto select_member.html; why doesn't `<h1>{{ activityname }}: Member Selection</h1>` work? :x

Comment: You do not need to include `slug_url_kwarg` or `slug_field` in your SelectView. `activityname` doesn't work in the template because it has not been added to the template context. You can just continue to use `activity.name` which was already in the template context.

Comment: I tried `<h1>{{ activity.name }}: Member Selection</h1>` but the activity name is still not showing up :/

Comment: Ah yes, you are using a `ListView` which would load all `Activity` objects instead of just one. You can iterate over all `Activity` inside of the template from the list `object_list` which gets automatically added to the context. Try `{% for activity in object_list %} <h1>{{ activity.name }}</h1>{% endfor %}`.

Comment: Tried that but am now getting the names of all existing activities. How do I limit to just the one that has been selected?

Comment: Hi Noah, would be awesome if you could help me a little further with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952821/creating-a-drop-down-menu-of-member-ids

Answer (score 1):

It is not the right way of defining a url. I recommend reading the [relevant section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) in the Django documentation about how to create a url for a view.

```
url(r'^activity/(?P<name>\W+)/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
```

Apart from that, there is another issue that needs to be addressed. Since you need to fetch the object by its name, you need to change `slug_url_kwarg` and `slug_field` to `name` in your view class:

```
class SelectView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'expcore/select_member.html'
    model = Activity
    slug_url_kwarg = 'name'
    slug_field = 'name'
```

Make sure to always leverage `{% url %}` template tag when creating a url in your template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'select_member' activity.name %}">{{ activity.name }}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a model variable should be used in a template, but you cannot put a model variable in a url(). You should use:

```
url(r'/activity/(?P<activityid>[0-9a-zA-z\.\_]+)/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view),
```

and then inspect "activityid" to verify whether it corresponds to a known and existing page and eventually visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#s-examples)

Your urls.py

```
url(r'^activity/{{ models.Activity.name }}/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
```

Change it to

```
url(r'^activity/(?P<activity_name>[^/]+)/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
```

And while printing the path in template use

```
<li><a href="{% url 'select_member' activity.name %}">{{ activity.name }}</a></li>
```