# Creating a drop-down menu of Member IDs

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model Member that includes a specification called member_id.

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.SlugField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    mobile = models.SlugField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

I want to create a drop-down menu of stored member ID's for the user to choose from in `select_member.html`.

Right now, I have this in **forms.py**: (pretty sure it's wrong)

```
class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    memberid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.member_id.objects.all())
```

The following view:

```
class SelectView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'expcore/select_member.html'
  model = Activity

  def select_member(request):
    form = SelectForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = SelectForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/questions/')
    else:
      form = SelectForm()
    return render(request, 'select_member.html', {'form': form})
```

The url:

```
url(r'^activity/(?P<activityname>[^/]+)/member/$', views.SelectView.as_view(), name='select_member'),
```

And nothing in my select_member.html because I'm not sure what to put.

Can someone help me out with the form, view, and HTML? I want to be able to call all the member IDs but Member.member_id.objects.all() doesn't work.

Also, it would be great if someone could tell me how to correctly call all the stored member IDs - instead of the incorrect Member.member_id.objects.all().

Comment: do you not just need to put `{{ form }}`? I thought a `ModelChoiceField` made a select element anyway (In terms of your edit its just `Member.objects.values('member_id')` if I've understood correctly

Comment: Do you mean i just need to put {{ form }} in the html?

Answer (score 2):

**Member.objects.values('member_id')** gives you list of dictionaries with values structured as {'member_id': value}.

If you just want the ids, you can make **Member.objects.values_list('member_id', flat=True)** which will just give you list of member ids.

Anyways you try to use ModelChoiceField which expects a queryset of Model instances and you try to pass to it a list of slugs.

What you want to do is 
**ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.all(), to_field_name='member_id')**
Normally `ModelChoiceFields` gets id as option, but you can override it with `to_field_name` :

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L1129-L1144

Comment: Under classSelectForm(forms.Form) in my forms.py, when I changed it to `memberid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.all(), to_field_name='member_id')` I got an Attribute error saying that "type object 'Member' has no attribute 'member_id'". However, when I tried `memberid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.values_list('member_id', flat=True))` I didn't get an error (so I think it worked). Do you think you could help me out with the HTML, though? And is the View right?

Comment: Which Django are you using ?